# How to install Firefox 4 silently with customizations?

Tags: firefox, silent-install

I know that with Firefox 3.6, one could extract the installer, modify files such as "nonlocalized\defaults\pref\firefox.js" and "localized\browserconfig.properties", and then install Firefox silently with these modifications by running the "setup.exe -ms" command.

Now that Firefox 4 is out, I tried duplicating this behavior but found that the files mentioned above were nowhere to be found within the Firefox 4 installer. How, then, can I install Firefox 4 silently with customizations such as having the profile migrator disabled, a custom home page, etc.?

I have discovered that after extracting the Firefox 4 installer's files, the `core\override.ini` file can be created and set up to disable the profile migrator. Also, the `core\defaults\pref\firefox.js` file can be created and set up to disable the default browser check and such. However, I have yet to figure out how to set the home page. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it with all customizations is with [this helpful tool](http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/3637-tool-ffam-v10211/) dedicated only for creating a silent switchless installer for Firefox 18.

> It can be frustrating to manually reinstall Firefox with all its extensions, themes, personas and other add-ons. Even for those administrators who need to deploy Firefox on hundreds of network computers will find it a cumbersome task to do it manually. To assist you in building a silent Firefox installer with all of the settings preset, here is Firefox Addon Maker.

Comment: Update 2015: Firefox can sync your account now, so that tool may be unneeded. However to really make the installation silent, you need to add the account to Firefox. And [I don't know how](http://superuser.com/questions/878446/auto-add-my-account-to-firefox-when-installing-it-silently).

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory as firefox.js create another file called prefs.js enter the following string:

user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.your homepage.com/");

Comment: this currently doesn't work with Firefox 4+

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, Firefox 4 has introduced some significant changes to how Firefox handles the configuration files.
The configuration files now reside in a package file called **'omni.jar'** you can over-ride the settings by creating new configuration files and placing into the **'defaults\pref\'** folder or editing and repackaging the 'omni.jar' file.

However, the **'browser.startup.homepage'** is not being accepted using this method - as this is a suspected bug it has been filed with Mozilla.

After going through several other options I've devised and tested a consistent and simple way of applying the customisations to a Firefox 4 installation. There is one limitation as detailed in the instructions, it may be a good or a bad thing depending on your deployment situation and requirements. 
See here for more information: http://www.itsupportguides.com/configmgr-sccm/firefox-set-default-home-page-for-all-users

Please note, I have also updated the original article to use this process. ( http://www.itsupportguides.com/configmgr-sccm/install-and-configure-firefox-silently )

Hopefully this will suit your requirements!